# Issue with loading the Roberta-base model

Tags: python, pytorch, roberta-language-model

I am trying to use the Roberta-base model using `AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('roberta-base')` but I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Failed to import transformers.modeling_tf_utils because of the following error (look up to see its traceback):
No module named 'tensorflow.python.keras.engine.keras_tensor'
```

I have tried to install tensorflow but still the same error. Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install with GPU, try this:

```
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow-gpu
```

See [here](https://velog.io/@jypark/Everything-you-need-for-Sentence-BERT-errors) for more details.

Comment: works great, thanks